# Showing messages for service worker states

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have been working on Service Worker for the last week, and currently have a great install for caching files offline and push notifications.

There's one last thing, I want to be able to show messages in the UI for certain states of service worker, currently I have the following code for the activated state:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange',function(event) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.controller.addEventListener('statechange', function() {
if (this.state === 'activated') {
  document.getElementById('offlineNotification').classList.remove('hidden');
}
});
});
}
```

And now I want to create a message for the install state, allowing me to show a message similar to something like "Offline service is updating", if anyone who is working on this, and knows how to do it, please let me know.

I have already tried the same code but with "if (this.state === 'installing')"

and

"if (this.state === 'install'"

Neither seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

A service worker has a lifecycle which is completely separate from your web page.
To install a service worker for your site, you need to register it.

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    // Perform install steps
});
```

When we're installed, the activation step will follow and this is a great opportunity for handling any management of old caches.

```
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    // Perform activate steps, Typically cache management.
});
```

After the activation step, the service worker will control all pages that fall under its scope, though the page that registered the service worker for the first time won't be controlled until it's loaded again.

Once a service worker is in control, it will be in one of two states: `either the service worker will be terminated` to save memory, or `it will handle fetch and message events` which occur when a network request or message is made from your page.
You may also try something like,

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(reg) {
        // updatefound is fired if service-worker.js changes.
        reg.onupdatefound = function() {
          var installingWorker = reg.installing;

          installingWorker.onstatechange = function() {
            switch (installingWorker.state) {
              case 'installed':
                if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                  // At this point, the old content will have been purged and the fresh content will have been added to the cache.
                  // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is available; please refresh."
                  console.log('New or updated content is available.');
                } else {
                  // At this point, everything has been precached.
                  // It's the perfect time to display a "Content is cached for offline use." message.
                  console.log('Content is now available offline!');
                }
                break;

              case 'redundant':
                console.error('The installing service worker became redundant.');
                break;
            }
          };
        };
      }).catch(function(e) {
        console.error('Error during service worker registration:', e);
      });
    }
```

Comment: As I said in the OP, I already know how to install service worker and I already have a service worker install, I didn't need to code lol. What I need is some way of showing an update notification in the UI (IE: Not console log, the actual webpage), just like you can for activate, as I stated in the OP.

Comment: Distinguishing between an update versus first time install is exactly what I needed with the check for `navigator.serviceWorker.controller`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [live flowchart demo](https://serviceworke.rs/live-flowchart_demo.html) on the ServiceWorker Cookbook and at the [code snippet](https://github.com/zhukov/webogram/pull/993/files#diff-7beb27b5869971df5529b169e5d9bd81R41) used by Telegram to notify the user when there's an update.

Comment: For some reason the page you've linked above doesn't scroll on my phone or even the iPad.

Comment: I filed an issue in the ServiceWorker Cookbook repo (https://github.com/mozilla/serviceworker-cookbook/issues/254). If you can, please add more details to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `this` in your code always refers to the `activated` service worker for your page.

`navigator.serviceWorker.controller` will only ever refer to **one** service worker for your page, the one currently in control.  If another service worker is installed while that service worker is in control of your page, it will be 'queued up', so to speak, in another field on your `ServiceWorkerRegistration` (namely, `installing` or `waiting`).

What you want is to refer to the various states on this `ServiceWorkerRegistration` (instead of your `navigator.serviceWorker.controller`) inside an `updatefound` event handler (instead of `controllerchange`):

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('serviceWorker.js');
  // Or, if not using async/await...
  //navigator.serviceWorker.register('serviceWorker.js').then(function(registration) {
  registration.addEventListener('updatefound', function(e) {
    const newSw = e.target.installing || e.target.waiting;
    newSw.addEventListener('statechange', function() {
      if (this.state === 'activated') {
         document.getElementById('offlineNotification').classList.remove('hidden');
      /* else if handlers for any of the following (or, better yet, a switch statement):
           'installing'
           'installed'
           'activating'
           'activated' (handled above)
           'redundant'
       */
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I believe that `controllerchange` is only called when the controller legitimately changes, which will only happen when you've explicitly claimed control of your clients in the service worker via `skipWaiting()` and `clients.claim()` or if you're fiddling around in dev tools and force the new service worker to take control.  As such, you'll never see `installing` on that controller since it has already progressed beyond `installing`, `installed`, and `activating` in order to trigger the `controllerchange` event.

Some helpful links:

> [MDN - ServiceWorkerContainer.controller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/controller)
>
> [MDN - ServiceWorkerRegistration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration)
>
> [MDN - ServiceWorker.onstatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker/onstatechange)
>
> [A detailed demonstration of service worker lifecycle and state change detection](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/service-worker/registration-events/index.html)